# How can I view the contents of the Bicep modules that I have placed in a Bicep Repository in an Azure Container Registry?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-bicep

When I look at the repositories in the portal, it shows me the version and the manifest, but how do I see the contents of the .bicep files that I have published there.

If I do a 'bicep restore' I am able to see the contents in the local cache, but even in there its not the original file.

I need to be able to show these modules so people using them can see what parameters are required etc.  Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way of extracting the contents of a certain version of an image in ACR is by REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/blob/get?tabs=HTTP), and even then you would get an ARM-tempate, as I think the `az bicep publish` compiles the bicep when pushing it to the private registry.